# Apache regex for location

Tags: regex, apache

What regex do I need to use in `<Location>` in Apache for the below two URLs?

1. Deny this url completely: http://www.example.com/event or http://www.example.com/event/

   I used something like below and it still not blocking:

   ```
   <Location ^/event/.+$>
       Deny from all
   </Location>
   ```
2. Allow this url: http://www.example.com/event/monthly/index.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you with the addition of the `~` character.

```
<Location ~ "/event/?$">
```